# How would I make a random object move in this code?

Tags: java, animation

Here is the deal, basically I have to have a code that has a bucket that can catch the falling fruit and every time it catches it you get a point a new fruit falls.

So I know how to make the bucket move and how to make the fruit go again once it reaches the bottom. However, I don't know how to make it actually fall. So far i got a switch but no idea what to do with it. I got the fruit popping up in random places which is a start. Anyways, here is my code. All help appreciated. Again, i need to have a random fruit drop once one of them reaches the bottom.

```css
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import acm.graphics.GOval;
import acm.graphics.GPolygon;
import acm.graphics.GRect;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class FruitCatcher extends GraphicsProgram {
 private static final int APPLET_WIDTH = 500;
 private static final int APPLET_HEIGHT = 500;
 private static final int BUCKET_X = 250;
 private static final int BUCKET_Y = 500;
 private static final int BUCKET_SPEED = 10;
 private static final int BUCKET_SPEED2 = -10;

 private GPolygon Bucket;

 public void init() {
  setSize(APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT);
  addKeyListeners();
 }

 public void run() {
  RandomGenerator random = new RandomGenerator();

  makeBucket();
  for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

   int randomX = random.nextInt(0, 300 - 20);

   addFruit(i, randomX, 0);
  }
  while (true)
   ;

 }

 public void makeBucket() {
  Bucket = new GPolygon(BUCKET_X, BUCKET_Y);
  Bucket.addVertex(-60, 0);
  Bucket.addVertex(-70, -85);
  Bucket.addVertex(10, -85);
  Bucket.addVertex(0, 0);

  add(Bucket);
  Bucket.setFilled(true);
  Bucket.setFillColor(Color.GRAY);
 }

 public void addFruit(int a, int x, int y) {

  switch (a) {
  case 1:
   GRect Banana = new GRect(x, y, 10, 60);
   Banana.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
   Banana.setFilled(true);
   add(Banana);
   break;
  case 2:
   GOval lime = new GOval(x, y, 20, 20);
   lime.setColor(Color.GREEN);
   lime.setFilled(true);
   add(lime);
   break;
  case 3:
   GOval Orange = new GOval(x, y, 30, 30);
   Orange.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
   Orange.setFilled(true);
   add(Orange);
  }

 }

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
  int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
  switch (keyCode) {
  case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
   if (Bucket.getX() > 0) {
    Bucket.move(-BUCKET_SPEED, 0);
   }
   break;
  case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
   if (Bucket.getX() < APPLET_WIDTH) {
    Bucket.move(BUCKET_SPEED, 0);
   }
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

In my code you can see a while (true) I am just assuming that is where I would write it. However, I am at a little loss what would actually go there.

Comment: What isn't working?  Throwing everything up and saying "finish the project" doesn't give us much to go on.  (And code snippets are for complete html/js/css, not java.)

Comment: Well I assume I put something up top in the while(true) loop since that is where I run the code. However, I am having a problem putting the bottom of the code in my add fruit method up top in the while method. You can't just do BLANK.move(0,2); or whatever since there is nothing to put.

Answer (score 2):

- You need to keep a list of references to all the fruits, so you can manipulate them later
- Each iteration of the game loop, move each fruit down
- You may want to implement some timing mechanism, so that the fruit
  speed is not dependent on the CPU speed.

  ```
  package jsyn;

  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Component;
  import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import acm.graphics.GOval;
  import acm.graphics.GPolygon;
  import acm.graphics.GRect;
  import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
  import acm.util.RandomGenerator;

  import java.awt.event.*;

  public class FruitCatcher extends GraphicsProgram {
  private static final int APPLET_WIDTH = 500;
  private static final int APPLET_HEIGHT = 500;
  private static final int BUCKET_X = 250;
  private static final int BUCKET_Y = 500;
  private static final int BUCKET_SPEED = 10;
  private static final int BUCKET_SPEED2 = -10;

  //Speed of fruit falling
  private static final int FRUIT_PX_PER_MS = 10;

  private GPolygon Bucket;

  public void init() {
      setSize(APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT);
      addKeyListeners();
      fruits = new ArrayList<Component>();
  }

  // Keep list of fruits
  List<GObject> fruits;

  public void run() {
      RandomGenerator random = new RandomGenerator();

      makeBucket();
      for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

          int randomX = random.nextInt(0, 300 - 20);

          addFruit(i, randomX, 0);
      }

      long last = System.currentTimeMillis();
      while (true) {
          long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
          update(current - last);
          last = current;
      }
  }

  void update(long delta) {
      for (GObject fruit : fruits) {
          //this code may not work, replace with code that moves fruit down
          fruit.setLocation(fruit.getX(), fruit.getY() + delta * FRUIT_PX_PER_MS);
      }
  }

  public void makeBucket() {
      Bucket = new GPolygon(BUCKET_X, BUCKET_Y);
      Bucket.addVertex(-60, 0);
      Bucket.addVertex(-70, -85);
      Bucket.addVertex(10, -85);
      Bucket.addVertex(0, 0);

      add(Bucket);
      Bucket.setFilled(true);
      Bucket.setFillColor(Color.GRAY);
  }

  public void addFruit(int a, int x, int y) {

      switch (a) {
      case 1:
          GRect Banana = new GRect(x, y, 10, 60);
          Banana.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
          Banana.setFilled(true);
          add(Banana);
          fruits.add(Banana);
          break;
      case 2:
          GOval lime = new GOval(x, y, 20, 20);
          lime.setColor(Color.GREEN);
          lime.setFilled(true);
          add(lime);
          fruits.add(lime);
          break;
      case 3:
          GOval Orange = new GOval(x, y, 30, 30);
          Orange.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
          Orange.setFilled(true);
          add(Orange);
          fruits.add(Orange);
      }

  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
      int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
      switch (keyCode) {
      case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
          if (Bucket.getX() > 0) {
              Bucket.move(-BUCKET_SPEED, 0);
          }
          break;
      case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
          if (Bucket.getX() < APPLET_WIDTH) {
              Bucket.move(BUCKET_SPEED, 0);
          }
          break;
      }
  }
  }
  ```